# reading binary file into a text box

Tags: c#, textbox

I am trying to read 2 values in a binary file and put the 1st value in text box 3 and the 2nd value in text box 4. The 2 values that need to be read from file were created with text boxes 1 and 2 and saved to file with the 1st button. On click of button 2 it is supposed to read the file and put the values in the right spots. I am not sure if it is not reading correctly or if it is not writing correctly. When I click the button to read and display the boxes show this:
    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[test.Form1+ore]

Code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace test
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [Serializable]
    public class ore
    {
        public float Titan;
        public float Eperton;
    }
    ore b1 = null;
    ore b2 = null;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        b2 = new ore();
        b1 = new ore();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 1st text box input is float
        float tempFloat;


        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            b1.Titan = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");



    }


    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 2nd text box input is float
        float tempFloat;
        if (float.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out tempFloat))
        {
            b2.Eperton = tempFloat;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("uh oh");


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // supposed to save list to file 
        List<ore> oreData = new List<ore>();
        oreData.Add(b1);
        oreData.Add(b2);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, oreData);
        fs.Close();
    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // 3rd text box 
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //4th text box
    }

    List<ore> books = new List<ore>(); // create list
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        List<ore> books = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        if (books.Count > 1)
        {

            textBox3.Text = books.ToString();//update the 3rd text box
            textBox4.Text = books.ToString();//update the 4th text box

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i need for ex. books[0] to go to text box 3 and books[1] to go to text box 4. Commented for added information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wondering if you have really asked for what you want, because you effectively answer your own question in your comment...

```
List<ore> books = new List<ore>(); // create list
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("ore.dat", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    List<ore> books = (List<ore>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
    fs.Close();

    if (books != null)
    {
        if (books.Count > 0)
            textBox3.Text = books[0].SomeProperty.ToString();//update the 3rd text box
        if (books.Count > 1)
            textBox4.Text = books[1].SomeProperty.ToString();//update the 4th text box

    }
}
```

Note the use of *SomeProperty* - this is because each item in `books` is an instance of the object `ore`, so you will need to substitute the appropriate property (Titan or Eperton) from `ore` in place of my *SomeProperty* place holder.. If you just do a `ToString()` on `ore` then you will get back the name of the type as a string, rather than any individual value in it - unless you have overridden the `ToString()`.

Comment: this worked awesome im getting the same value for box 3 and box 4 ill try and figure out why